# Duplicate a client request to multiple servers

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, apache2

Suppose I have two server endpoints:

- http://server1/endpoint
- http://server2/endpoint

and whenever an URL `/consumedata` is requested by the client it should bind the request/response to `server1/endpoint` and also copy the request to `server2/endpoint` where the request can just sink or get a HTTP 200 response. Response JSON still comes from server1. How do I do it?

Comment: So basically you want the web server to duplicate the client request to the second endpoint and ignore the response from the second endpoint?

Comment: You've given no details of the criticality of the coupling in the transaction, nor any details of the underlying infastructure (are these highly available? How is the HA implemented?) nor where you expect the magic to happen

Comment: @jotik yeah, the second endpoint should just be a sink

Comment: @symcbean i expect the flow to proceed with req/resp bound to first endpoint only. Second is required to extend the legacy feature set and it comes with its own HA model of server2 being an LB infront of the extended service. A 200 itself should suffice from server2 or even a plain sink with no response is fine.